# haskell join multi-level monad

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

I'm learning haskell, and trying to use applicative functors as much as possible instead of monad. It is very neat and easy to compose.  However, occasionally some types like `IO [IO [a]]` or `IO Maybe IO Maybe a` will rise in the code, which cause me big trouble. Apparently monad become inevitable in these scenarios.

I know there is a flat operation like `join:: m (m a) -> m a` for single level monads. Is there anything similar for multi-level monads? Anything in monad transformers?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you note that `m (n _)` is a monad transformer then you can define this operation. This is certainly the case when we notice that `IO (Maybe a)` is the same as `MaybeT IO a`: we then just use `MaybeT`'s `join`. We can do this in no small part due to the fact that Maybe and IO "layer" especially nicely.

On the other hand, not all "composed" monads are monad transformers. In particular, `IO [a]` isn't really one. [The true ListT transformer](https://gist.github.com/tel/8efa535a1d4a95646adc) we'd like to have and to `join` looks like

```
newtype ListT m a = ListT { runListT :: m (Maybe (a, ListT m a)) }
```

It is the case that we can turn `IO [a]` into `ListT IO a` and visa-versa, but it is *not* the case that these operations invert one another. Truly, `IO [a]` is not a monad in its own right and cannot be `join`ed.

Comment: The short answer is that `newtype ListT m a = ListT (m [a])` follows the pattern of other types which are successfully monads, but fails to follow the rules itself for general `m`. I was being a little imprecise—such a `ListT m` *is* a monad exactly when `[]` and `m` commute, e.g. `m [a]` is isomorphic to `[m a]`. This is [noted in the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-List.html). There's also [this page on the Wiki](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ListT_done_right).

Comment: From a more operational POV, the problem is that `m [a]` varies from the `ListT` I gave in my answer by consolidating all of the `m`-effects to the top. This means that the list effects and the `m`-effects run in batches instead of interwoven which is necessary to satisfy the monad transformer laws in general.

Comment: If you look at [my gist detailing the `ListT`-done-right implementation](https://gist.github.com/tel/8efa535a1d4a95646adc) you'll see that the `stream` function allows us to convert from `ListT m a` to `m [a]`. Notably, this operation demonstrates the "smashing all of the `m`-effects together" problem. It also, as I noted, "blows stacks" since it means you cannot actually stream the list lazily—all of the `m`-effects get forced at once. (I'm not sure, in the light of the morning now, why I called it `stream`, actually)

Comment: I kind of feel it is similar to the case of zipList but can not prove/disprove against the monad laws.

For `IO [ IO [a] ]`, currently I use `fmap sequence` to transform them into `IO IO [[a]]`, then do `join` and `fmap join`. It will become `IO [a]` but I think it is pretty ugly.

Comment: That mechanism completely pulls apart the `IO` and `[]` effects. It works so long as the particular effects you're interested in have that `IO [a] ~ [IO a]`, e.g. the effects commute. This might be the case for some `IO` effects, but you'll notice that your consumption of the result list and the effects that occur in the real world will become desynchronized. This is most patently bad in the case of "lazy IO" which is either forced to be strict (by the joins and sequences on `IO`) or non-deterministic due to the fact that resource utilization (e.g. file handles) doesn't commute with list use.

Comment: How about ConT [a]? Is it monadic and commutative?
If yes then I can restrict all IO effects into some IoConT and get the transformers for free.

Comment: As `Cont` is the "mother of all monads", my guess is that since there exists any non-commuting monad then Cont is non-commuting.

Answer (score 1):

Monads do not commute in general, but you can provide all particular cases, that you need:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Control.Monad

class (Monad m, Monad n) => Swappable m n where
    swap :: m (n a) -> n (m a)

instance Swappable [] IO where
    swap = sequence

instance Swappable Maybe IO where
    swap  Nothing  = return Nothing
    swap (Just mx) = fmap return mx

cut :: Swappable m n => m (n (m a)) -> n (m a)
cut = liftM join . swap

squash :: Swappable m n => n (m (n (m a))) -> n (m a)
squash = (>>= cut)
```

An example:

```
x :: IO [IO [()]]
x = return $ map (\s -> putStrLn s >> return [()]) ["ab","c"]

y :: IO (Maybe (IO (Maybe ())))
y = return $ Just $ putStrLn "z" >> return (Just ())

main = squash x >> squash y
```

prints

```
ab
c
z
```

**EDIT**

You can avoid defining new typeclass by providing an instance of `Traversable` (there are instances for `Maybe` and `[]` in `Data.Traversable`):

```
import Data.Traversable as T
import Control.Monad

cut :: (Traversable t, Monad t, Monad m) => t (m (t a)) -> m (t a)
cut = liftM join . T.sequence

squash :: (Traversable t, Monad t, Monad m) => m (t (m (t a))) -> m (t a)
squash = (>>= cut)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I feel it is more like another adhoc transformer implementation...